# Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding but SLF4J traces lost

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

In a "classic" Java development, without maven, we use a third party library that uses **SLF4J**. In this way: (Model A)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PLGSharepointClientOnline.class);
...
log.debug("some message...");
```

Our code uses **Log4j v2**. In "migrated mode" from **Log4j v1** through the binding (log4j-1.2.api.jar). In this way (Model B):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PruebaPLG.class);
...
log.debug("some message...");
```

As we have read, in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/, by using the **log4j-slf4j-impl.jar adapter**, the SLF4J traces would still work.

We use these libraries, but the traces from SLF4J (Model A) are **lost**.

```
log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
log4j-api-2.17.1.jar

log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Comment: Do you have any other SLF4J bindings on your classpath (libraries with `slf4j` in the name or `logback-classic`)?

Comment: No one more, Piotr

Comment: did you find the reason?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't